# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un for en un while?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, numpy

Estoy tratando de convertir este bucle for en un while, pero no he podido sinceramente. ¿Alguna idea de qué puedo hacer?

```
import random 
import numpy as np

alfabeto = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
x = int()
y = int()
filas = int(input("Cantidad de filas: "))
Columna = int(input("Cantidad de Columnas: "))

arreglo = np.empty((filas, Columna), dtype=str)
for x in range(filas):
    for y in range(Columna):
        if(len(alfabeto)>0):
            let = random.choice(alfabeto)
            alfabeto.remove(let)
            arreglo[x, y] = let


print(arreglo)
```

Comment: Ya que tus bucles se basan en contadores (usas `range()`) basta que inicialices el contador antes de entrar al bucle, por ejemplo `y=0`, y pongas como condición del bucle: `while y<Columna`. Luego dentro del bucle haces lo mismo que tenías, pero añades como última instrucción `y=y+1`

Answer (score 0):

Unicamente declaras las variables que en este contexto serán tus iteradores, luego `while` comprobará la clausula booleana, mira como dentro de cada `while` su iterador se actualiza.

```py
arreglo = np.empty((filas, Columna), dtype=str)
x = 0
while x < filas:
   y = 0
   while y < Columnas:
      if(len(alfabeto) > 0):
         let = random.choice(alfabeto)
         alfabeto.remove(let)
         arreglo[x, y] = let
      y += 1
   x += 1
```